# How to show present privileges on table in IBM DB2 Z/OS with SQL

Tags: sql, db2, zos, db2-zos

Is there an SQL way to show the privileges present on a table or view in DB2 Z/OS? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
select * from sysibm.magic_table where table_name = 'users'

|TABLE_NAME|PRIVILEGE_TYPE|USER_OR_GROUP_NAME|
|     USERS|        INSERT|              ANDI|
|     USERS|        SELECT|            ADMINS|
```

Is that possible?

Comment: unlikely to be that simple. Have a look at the DB System tables https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_catalogtablesintro.html, Sysresauth looks like one to look at

Comment: For Cics programs, it is the Bind that gets the access (rather than the actual end user).

Comment: That would be [SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystabauthtable.html) I think.

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio, I think you are right. `SELECT
 grantee,
 screator,
 stname,
 tcreator,
 ttname,
 updatecols,
 alterauth,
 deleteauth,
 indexauth,
 insertauth,
 selectauth,
 updateauth
FROM
 SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH
WHERE
 TTNAME = 'MY_TABLE'
 AND TCREATOR = 'MY_SCHEMA'`. I will test tomorrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This query tells the user / role names in the `grantee` column and the various assigned rigths in the `...auth` columns where `Y` = right present, `G` = right present and right to grant it to others.

```
SELECT
    grantee,
    screator,
    stname,
    tcreator,
    ttname,
    updatecols,
    alterauth,
    deleteauth,
    indexauth,
    insertauth,
    selectauth,
    updateauth
FROM
    SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH
WHERE
    TTNAME = 'MY_TABLE'
    AND TCREATOR = 'MY_SCHEMA'
```

Sample result set:

```
|GRANTEE  |SCREATOR |STNAME  |TCREATOR |TTNAME  |UPDATECOLS|ALTERAUTH|DELETEAUTH|INDEXAUTH|INSERTAUTH|SELECTAUTH|UPDATEAUTH|
============================================================================================================================
|MY_SCHEMA|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |         G|         |         G|         G|         G|
|USER2    |MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |         Y|         |         Y|         Y|         Y|
|USER3    |MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |         Y|         |         Y|         Y|         Y|
|GROUP1   |MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |         Y|         |         Y|         Y|         Y|
|GROUP2   |MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |         Y|         |         Y|         Y|         Y|
|GROUP3   |MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |          |         |          |         Y|          |
|GROUP4   |MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|MY_SCHEMA|MY_TABLE|          |         |         Y|         |         Y|         Y|         Y|
```

[IBM documentation of SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystabauthtable.html) (Thanks to @mustaccio)

Comment: The link to IBM documentation is dead. Could you update please ?

Comment: Here you are @Minh-TrietLÊ